# Symfony 2.1 - Client side validation is only working for required contraint

Tags: validation, symfony, orm, symfony-2.1

As the assertions of `Entities` changed from `MinLength` and `MaxLength` to `Length`, `Min` and `Max` to `Range`, the validator guesser didn't follow these changes and the `max_length` attribute doesn't get filled, so HTML validation doesn't work for `length`.

I think there should be a new case for `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length` in `guessMaxLengthForConstraint` function in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorTypeGuesser.php`

Or is it a solved.

I'm using 2.1.6 but I tried 2.1.7 and there is no difference
Im using this:

```
/**
* @var float $height
*
* @ORM\Column(name="height", type="decimal", nullable=true)
* 
* 
* @Assert\Range(
*      min = "20",
*      max = "96",
*      minMessage = "You must be at least 20 tall",
*      maxMessage = "You cannot taller than 96"

* )      
* @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration_step_two","profile_measurement"})  
* @Assert\Regex(pattern= "/[0-9]/",message="Require number only") 
* @Assert\MinLength(10)
*/
```

Comment: Please have a look at the public issue tracking system at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues. If the bug is not reported there, please make the effort of posting it or even fixing the bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added group validation to them and its finally work